# Есть ли смысл в дешевом vps хостинге?

Tags: хостинг, vps

Заканчивается мой виртуальный хостинг на hostland, и я решил перейти на другой (hostland не устроил). Начал искать другие виртуальные хостинги, и кроме плохих отзывов ничего другого не нашел. Протестил несколько виртуальных хостингов и все меня не устроили, кроме timeweb и webhost1. Критерий был прост: на хостинг заливается чистая yii2 и тестится на pagespeed. Каждый хостинг показал разные значения, а у timeweb и webhost1 были лучшие показатели: смартфон — 82, пк — 91. У остальных хостингов показатели падали, как правило, за кеш и за сжатие. Но, увы, у timeweb и у webhost1 отвратительные отзывы. Каждый третий пишет, что сайты очень часто лежат.

Сейчас наткнулся на vps хостинг от джино за 100 рублей в месяц. Ходят слухи, что если переехать на vps — про проблемы недоступности сайта можно забыть.

Цель у меня такая: захостить 6 html сайтов (лендингов), с прикрученным к ним phpmailer и 1 на dle или wordpress. Средняя посещаемость у всех сайтов вместе взятых не превышает 300 человек в сутки. + к каждому сайту подкрутить кеширование и сжатие, которое просит pagespeed.

Я ни разу не знаком с vps, но в сети я уже нашел несколько гайдов по настройке сервера, поэтому, мне кажется, с настройкой у меня особых проблем не возникнет (нужно будет только сжатие и кеш как-нибудь подключить).

Так вот, хотелось бы узнать, есть ли мне смысл в таком vps, или проблем у меня будет больше?
Хватит ли мне 500 мгц и 500 мб озу?
Действительно ли у меня не будет проблем с доступам к сайтам?

Comment: Вы как-то неправильно проверяете vps. Кэш и сжатие зависят только и исключительно от того, как вы — ЛИЧНО ВЫ И НИКТО ДРУГОЙ — настроите ваш веб-сайт. Всю конфигурацию кэширования и сжатия пишете только вы только своими собственными руками в вашем любимом текстовом редакторе в файле конфигурации, который находится где-то в каталоге /etc вашего vps. Если вы этого не делали, значит вы вообще непонятно что сравнивали тогда.

Comment: Вообще, с технической точки зрения vps есть смысл различать только по следующим характеристикам: процессор, память, диск (тип и количество всего этого), наличие RAID, способ виртуализации, скорость интернета, пинг (плюс, возможно, влияние соседей по серверу, но не знаю как это измерять). Всё остальное вы настраиваете самостоятельно. Из всего этого pagespeed тестирует разве что пинг.

Comment: андрей, вы меня не правильно поняли. Я тестировал **виртуальный** (шаред, обычный) хостинг через pagespeed, а не vps.

Comment: V в слове VPS тоже означает **виртуальный**, и у timeweb и webhost1 помимо шареда есть и VPS тоже, поэтому совершенно неудивительно, что я вас неправильно понял :) Тогда, наверно, весь первый абзац можно из вопроса выкинуть как не касающийся темы вопроса

Comment: А «хватит ли» можно приблизительно проверить в любой подручной виртуальной машине

Comment: Брал термины с википедии: там шаред — виртуальный хостинг, а vps — виртуальный сервер.

Comment: А протестировать не могу. знаний не хватает, поэтому здесь вопрос и задаю

Comment: VDS/VPS это тоже хостинг, википедия вас запутала :) Если называть шаред шаредом, путаницы будет меньше.

Comment: В любом случае, если я правильно понимаю формат ruSO, этот вопрос не по теме, он слишком общий и на него трудно ответить однозначно, скорее всего вопрос закроют

Comment: https://beget.com/ru/order/start

Answer (score 1):

Пользовался хостингом Jino.ru много лет. До тех пор, пока не начал пользоваться Cron заданиями всё устраивало. Что хостинг, что VPS у них грешат зависаниями Cron. Чтобы исправить нужно коннектиться по SSH к хостингу и убивать Cron процессы ручками. Раза три за несколько месяцев проделывал сие действие. А если у вас на хостинге не активирована услуга SSH доступ, то придётся заплатить денежку за её активацию чтобы убить зависший процесс. Качество каналов оставляет желать лучшего. Использовал пару скриптов соединения с внешними ресурсами для парсинга инфы каждую минуту и имел частые отказы в соединении. При этом домашний комп не имел проблем с соединением к тем же самым ресурсам на протяжении того же времени с теми же скриптами. Они работали в параллель.

Ушёл на reg.ru и пока всё работает нормально на VPS. Хвалить не буду, но за 4 месяца использования самого дешёвого VPS проблем не испытывал. Имею сайт на WordPress и в будущем будет пару Java backend приложений.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не знакомы с командной строкой, не осложняйте себе жизнь.
Не смотрите на отзывы в инете они все куплены. Советую молодые компании, они ценят клиентов.
Откройте любую статью о настройке VPS под Worldpress, если вы думайте что осилите или у вас есть деньги на сис.админа тогда вперед.
При правильной настройке сервера , вам и 128 Озу + Подкачка будет хватать при такой посещаемости (Nginx + php-fpm)